# CakePHP 1.3 install in subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, deployment, cakephp, installation, subdirectory

I have to deploy my standard install of cakephp 1.3 on a shared host in a subdirectory.

Other answers to similar questions didn't work for me.

On localhost i have my dev space as a virtual host like

```
myproject.local.com
```

that on filesystem is `/var/www/myproject/`

and there there is the cakephp

so

```
/app
/app/webroot etc
```

I have mod_rewrite enabled.

If i want, with the same virtualhost, put my cakephp app under `/subfolder/`, and access to it as `myproject.local.com/subfolder/`, what i have to do?

Remember that i can't access to apache config files and i can't put nothing on root.

Any ideas?

It's possible to modify only the htaccess files in subfolder/, subfolder/app/, subfolder/app/webroot with RewriteBase?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could put the whole cakephp install in the subfolder. 
If your server allows .htaccess to be overridden then adding this to the .htaccess in the /subfolder/ will help

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
  RewriteEngine  on 
  RewriteRule ^/subfolder$       subfolder/app/webroot/     [L] 
  RewriteRule ^/subfolder/(.*)$ subfolder/app/webroot/$1  [L] 
</IfModule>
```

But this leaves your app and cake folders accessible from the web.. NotGood(TM)

Another way that I've not tried out yet, but I'm guessing will work is copying just the files from webroot into /subfolder/ then edit the index.php to define the locations of the cake libs

```
define('APP_DIR', './app');
define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', '/path/to/cake_1.3');
```

Then edit routes.php to add a custom route that takes the subfolder into account

```
Router::connect('/subfolder/:controller/:action*');
```

You may have to play with the routes a bit to get this working.
Good luck.